# How can I save INT in NVARCHAR column database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert

I have a stored procedure that saves an `INT` parameter into an `NVARCHAR` column.

If I do

```
DECLARE @VALORE AS INT
SET @VALORE = 90

INSERT INTO TABLE (VALORE) VALUES(@VALORE)
```

so if I select the valore from the database I can see this

```
90.0000
```

Comment: You could just convert it to a `NVARCHAR`, but what I'm not understanding is: why are you wanting to store an `INT` in a `NVARCHAR` column in the first place?

Comment: Why would you get `90.000` for an integer? There's no decimal component to an integer. And whether the `.` is a thousands separator or decimal point, are you hinting that you want to store a formatted number as a string in the database? If so, skip it - do your formatting at the presentation layer, keep data in the correct types in the database.

Comment: Always use the **most appropriate** datatype - if your values is an `INT` - *why on EARTH* do you want to store it as a `NVARCHAR`?? If it looks like an int, talks like an int, smells like an int - it ***IS*** an `INT` and should be stored as such

Comment: Are you sure VALORE isn't a numeric or decimal? That's the only way I can understand why you're getting 90.0000 back...

Comment: This isn't even a question.   Are you saying you do or don't want to get "90.0000" when you select from the database?   And what does the result you get at query time have to do with what is stored in the database?   https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (VALORE) VALUES(CAST(@VALORE AS VARCHAR(10))
```